# Tail bounds for sum of rectified gaussian variables

Tags: probability-distributions, distribution-tails, gaussian

Is there a concentration inequality for the rectified gaussian distribution? For example, let $u_i$, $i=1,...,n$ be a sequence of i.i.d. standard normal random variables. Is it possible to bound $P\left\{\left\vert n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n \max\{0,\,u_i\}-\mathbb E\left[n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n \max\{0,\,u_i\}\right]\right\vert\leq t\right\}$ for any $t\geq 0$?

Comment: The resultant random variable $v = \max\{0, u\}$ is also a sub-gaussian random variable. You can directly use the Chernoff-Hoeffding bounds once you have determined the sub-Gaussian parameter for this new random variable.